# Dos div del mismo tamaño y tamaño que dependa del div que tenga más contenido

Tags: css3

Tengo dos div que contienen texto , uno de ellos tiene más que el otro y quiero que la altura del div con menos texto sea igual que la altura del que tiene más.

Es decir que el tamaño no sea fijo. ¿Se podría hacer con css?

```css
#a,#b{
float:left;
border:1px solid;
}
section{
 width:75%;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
<div id="a">
 gdaskgdsadgsjagdsajvd
</div>
<div id="b">
zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
<P>aaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Sí se puede, por favor agrega el código html y css de dichos div.

Comment: Para que un tamaño no sea fijo puedes agregarle la propiedad `auto` para que se ajuste solo según el contenido del elemento y sus demás propiedades de CSS. Pero si quieres que la altura del que tiene menos texto sea igual a la que tiene más, suena a que ya le estás dando una altura definida a dicho div, es decir que esta ya sea fija, entonces exactamente qué es lo que buscas hacer?

Comment: ¿entonces para que sea igual que la que tiene más contenido es necesario un tamaño fijo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que buscas es FlexBox. Simplemente ponle `display:flex` a tu sección y el `div` de menor altura se adaptará al de mayor altura automáticamente:

```css
#a,
#b {
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
}

section {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:flex;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="a">
    gdaskgdsadgsjagdsajvd
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
    <P>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Hola lo que puedes hacer es darle un altura al `section` y a los divs ponerles una altura del 100%.

```css
section{
 height: 100px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

#a, #b{
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="a">
    gdaskgdsadgsjagdsajvd
  </div>
  <div id="b">
    zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz
    <p>aaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
  </div>
</section>
```